# Caso práctico para readFileSync()

Tags: nodejs, asincronismo

Buen día comunidad de StackOverflow!

Mi pregunta es muy teórica esta vez, estoy estudiando los métodos `readFile()` y `readFileSync()` del módulo `fs`.

Siendo la principal ventaja de nodejs el hecho de ejecutar operaciones asíncronas me queda la duda de por qué y para qué existe `readFileSync()`? No es cierto que podría tratar todos los casos con `readFile()`?

Dicho planteamiento me lleva a mi duda más importante: Existen casos donde sea más conveniente usar `readFileSync()` en vez de `readFile()`?

Gracias de antemano por su colaboración!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurren los siguientes casos de uso:

- simplicidad. A veces solo quieres leer un fichero para una tarea sencilla y utilizar la versión async implica un código mas complejo y menos legible.
- imposibilidad de usar asincronia. Este caso es raro y difícil de dar ejemplos pero alguna vez me he encontrado situaciones en las que era necesario bloquear el hilo o que hacerlo simplificaba mucho.

En conclusión, antes de tener herramientas como async/await introducir código asíncrono complica el código, lo hace menos legible y puede llegar a generar errores difíciles de depurar. No creo que costa una situación donde la versión sincrona sea mejor, pero a veces es más conveniente.

Ah y cuando estás aprendiendo node y no te empapas de los callbacks es la vía fácil que todos hemos cogido de novatos jaja

Comment: Muy agradecido por tu aporte. Me estoy dedicando desde un principio a aprender callbacks. Me gustaría un ejemplo práctico que refleje la importancia de readFileSync() porque salvo lo que comentas sobre simplicidad no veo una buena implementación del método síncrono, es decir, quien quisiera bloquear la ejecución de un programa y perder ciclos de maquina sabiendo que sólo se tiene disponible un hilo de ejecución?